# Read the files at the spesific commit with libgit2sharp

Tags: libgit2sharp

There is a bare repository, I have a commit id, and want to read all the files at that commit without cloning.

This `repository.Lookup<Tree>(repository.Commits.First().Tree.Sha)` code give me only the files that are in the commit but I want also other files that exists at that level.

How to do that?

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on the "but I want also other files that exists at that level." requirement. I'm not sure to really understand what you're after.

Comment: "git checkout <commit>" command updates all files in the working directory to match the specified commit. I want the same functionality in a bare repository without cloning it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding of your question is that you're willing to access the whole content of a commit, not only the first level of the commit. The code below will work against a bare (or a standard) repository and will allow one to recursively access and examine the content of a commit.

In order to make it easier for you to test drive it, it dumps information (git object meta data along with blob content) in the console output.

```
RecursivelyDumpTreeContent(repo, "", commit.Tree);

[...]

private void RecursivelyDumpTreeContent(IRepository repo, string prefix, Tree tree)
{
    foreach (var treeEntry in tree)
    {
        var path = prefix + treeEntry.Name;
        var gitObject = treeEntry.Target;

        var meta = repo.ObjectDatabase.RetrieveObjectMetadata(gitObject.Id);
        Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\t{4}", gitObject.Id, treeEntry.Mode, treeEntry.TargetType, meta.Size, path);

        if (treeEntry.TargetType == TreeEntryTargetType.Tree)
        {
            RecursivelyDumpTreeContent(repo, path + "/", (Tree)gitObject);
        }

        if (treeEntry.TargetType == TreeEntryTargetType.Blob)
        {
            Console.WriteLine((((Blob)gitObject).GetContentText()));
        }
    }
}
```

Would you precisely know the path of a specific file you'd like to access, use the indexer exposed by the `Commit` type in order to directly access the `GitObject` you're after.

For instance:

```
var blob = commit["path/to/my/file.txt"].Target as Blob;
```