# Host repository and save content in a database

Tags: c#, .net, libgit2sharp

Is it possible to self host a git repository with libgit2sharp and save the content of the repository (remote) in a database? This is needed, because i want to access the sources which where synchronized between the windows directory and the database in some application by retrieving data from the database.

**EDIT**

The repository will only contains scripts, such as IronPython, SQL and some XAML. So only text files will be stored in the repository (database).

Later i would like to access the scripts like: `ScriptManager.GetScript('/Scripts/Test.py')`. The `GetScript` method will return the script-content from the database. (Only as a simple example).

**EDIT**

[image]

LibGit2Sharp should be the hosting component. *Some client* should read the scripts directly from the database, without git.

**Solution**

[image]

I think this solution is more straight forward, becuase self hosting over LibGit2Sharp is not possible and not the best way. The problem was more over in the complete idea / architecture. I think the current solution is the best.

Thank you!

Comment: Could you please elaborate further about the kind of "content" are you will to export? Commits, Blobs, References, ....

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. I added more details to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Later i would like to access the scripts like: `ScriptManager.GetScript('/Scripts/Test.py')`

Well, if all you need is access the content of the file from the latest commit (ie. `Tip`) of the branch pointed at by `HEAD`, the following piece of code should do the trick:

```
using (var repo = new Repository("path/to/your/local/repo")
{
   var blob = repo.Head.Tip["/Scripts/Test.py"].Target as Blob;
   var content = blob.GetContentText();
}
```

### Update

If I correctly understand *"save the content of the repository (remote) in a database"*, you'd like to export the content of a repository in a database. The repository would be the "master" and the SyBase would be a read-only replica of it.

One thing cannot be achieved at this moment: Hosting the git repository server side with LibGit2Sharp and make it the endpoint git client interacts with. There's an opened feature request about this (see **[#90](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/90)**).

However, nothing prevents you for now to host your repository with git-daemon or a packaged tool (eg. **[Bonobo Git Server](https://bonobogitserver.com/)**) and use LibGit2sharp to ease the exporting task.

The code above shows how to extract a known file with LibGit2Sharp.

In order to blindly export the whole content of a Commit/Tree, see this **[SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30277093/read-the-files-at-the-spesific-commit-with-libgit2sharp/30286492#30286492)**.

Comment: Thank you, but how does Repository(...) resolve the path? I don't want to have any files on the server in the filesystem. Every thing should be stored in the database. I edited my question to provide some more information.

Comment: @BendEg Did that answer provide you with any help?

Comment: I changed the way implementing git in my software architecture. I use Bonobo as Git-Server and our software acts as a git client. We developed a server component which looks every 20 seconds on the git-server to pull the newest repository version of a configurable branch. So i don't do any thing by my self and it is working pretty nice. Thank you for your hints :)

Comment: i added my solution as an image to the question. Thank you again.